# How can i sort the values stored in a function?

Tags: eclipse, function, sorting

I have some values in gridlet.getActualCPUTime() function. Is there any way to sort these values.I am working in eclipse. Thank You.

Comment: Eclipse is just your IDE and is used for developing in many different programming languages. Which language is this?

Comment: it is in java..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are writing on Java.

[`gridlet.getActualCPUTime()`](http://www.cloudbus.org/cloudsim/doc/api/org/cloudbus/cloudsim/Cloudlet.html#getActualCPUTime()) returns `double` value, so all of you need is sorting it.
Add it to `ArrayList` for example. For example its sorting in ascending order.

```
ArrayList<Double> arrayList = new ArrayList<Double>();
//replace this cycle for urs
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    arrayList.add(gridlet.getActualCPUTime());
}
Collections.sort(arrayList);
```

if you need descending order

```
Collections.reverse(arrayList);
```